# TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined (line 2, file "Auto Fill Google Doc")

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, undefined

I am attempting to use an app script to link my Google Forms to a Google Doc template. I followed a video on YouTube step by step but for some reason, I am getting stuck on this error title

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined (line 2, file "Auto Fill Google Doc")

This is my script:

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  var reasonForInjury = e.values[0];
  var name = e.values[1];
  var location = e.values[2];
  var dateOfInjury = e.values[3];
  
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1qOXVwyh45nUJAWYgY7p7JdbexxrsNN-myLe8DQrn-Cs");
  var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1zxIQ-_JzIhbcvE3iBEDL0VtvZpCUtTCT");
  
  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(name + ", " + location, templateResponseFolder);
  
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  
  var body = doc.getBody()
  
  body.replaceText("{{Reason for Injury}}", reasonForInjury);
  body.replaceText("{{EE Name}}", name);
  body.replaceText("{{Location}}", location);
  body.replaceText("{{DOI}}", dateOfInjury);
  
  doc.saveAndClose();
  
}
```

The debugger says my values are undefined. How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

e is not defined in your code snippet. Therefore, you are potentially trying to read something that doesn't exist. Basically, you need to figure out how to define it. Where is it coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You are try to access the event object of [form submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) and you ran the code in the editor instead of creating an event(submitting form).

`e` is an event object that Apps Script passes to a function as an argument. The event object contains information about the context that caused the trigger to fire. Example is the values the user submitted. Event object is used for Triggers. Triggers let Apps Script run a function automatically when a certain event, such as submitting form, occurs.

To fix the issue, submit a form and add the event object in the parameter of your function.

**Your code should look like this:**

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var reasonForInjury = e.values[0];
  var name = e.values[1];
  var location = e.values[2];
  var dateOfInjury = e.values[3];

  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("id");
  var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("id");

  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(name + ", " + location, templateResponseFolder);

  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

  var body = doc.getBody()

  body.replaceText("{{Reason for Injury}}", reasonForInjury);
  body.replaceText("{{EE Name}}", name);
  body.replaceText("{{Location}}", location);
  body.replaceText("{{DOI}}", dateOfInjury);
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Logs from events can be seen at the **Execution** tab of your Apps Script.

**Further Reading:**

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [How to setup Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)